# Does PlayOrm support join conditions with OR/AND, self joins, and nested queries?

Tags: playorm

I need to adapt an existing application, that uses mysql as backend database, to work with hbase.I have a couple of questions:

1) Does it work as a JDBC driver that can be used by a java application?

2) Does it support "OR" in join conditions?
E.g.: "SELECT J.i_id, J.i_thumbnail from item I join item J on I.i_related1 = J.i_id or I.i_related2 = J.i_id or I.i_related3 = J.i_id or I.i_related4 = J.i_id or I.i_related5 = J.i_id where I.i_id = 1000;"

3) Does it support self joins?

4) Does it support nested queries?
E.g.: "SELECT i_id, i_title, a_fname, a_lname, SUM(ol_qty) AS orderkey FROM item 
INNER JOIN order_line
ON item.i_id = order_line.ol_i_id
INNER JOIN author
ON item.i_a_id = author.a_id
WHERE order_line.ol_o_id > (SELECT MAX(o_id) - 3333 FROM orders) 
AND item.i_subject = "ARTS"
GROUP BY i_id, i_title, a_fname, a_lname
ORDER BY orderkey DESC;"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes, it uses first level drivers for all NoSql databases internally. So it act as a 2nd level driver. However, it will not allow you to pass native queries for the NoSql database.

2, 3 and 4) You may see the example of JOINS it supports [here](https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/alvazan/test/TestJoins.java)